# How to download a file from azure blob in Asp.Net core?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to download an image from azure blob in Asp.Net Core using the below code. But i am getting

> "The given path's format is not supported"

My Code:

```
StorageCredentials creds = new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey);
            CloudStorageAccount account = new CloudStorageAccount(creds, useHttps: true);
            CloudBlobClient client = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            container = client.GetContainerReference(blobName);
```

// For download

```
public async void DownloadAsync(string path, string[] names)
{
    string MyPath = path.Replace("https://browsercontent.blob.core.windows.net/blob1/", "");
    CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(MyPath+names[0]);
    path = path + names[0];
    await blockBlob.DownloadToFileAsync(path, FileMode.Create);
}
```

[image]

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: What is the full path (`path`)?

Comment: "https://browsercontent.blob.core.windows.net/blob1/Content/User/3.png"                                       this is my full path value

Answer (score 1):

The first argument `DownloadToFileAsync` to is the path to the file *on disk*, that should be a local path like "C:\Temp\3.png" for example. See example below:

```
public async void DownloadAsync(string path, string[] names)
{
    string MyPath = path.Replace("https://browsercontent.blob.core.windows.net/blob1/", "");
    CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(MyPath+names[0]);
    var localPath = @"C:\Temp" + names[0];
    await blockBlob.DownloadToFileAsync(localPath , FileMode.Create);
}
```

Some other tips:

- Next time when you ask a question add the location where the exception occurs
- Avoid having `async void`. Return a Task like `public async Task DownloadAsync(string path, string[] names)` so you can await that method

Comment: Hi Peter, Thanks for your answer. . How can I download the files from online blob storage.  .

Comment: Well, if you follow my example the online blob will be stored at C:\temp\png.3, isn't that what you need? If you do not need it in code then you can use [Azure Storage Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/)

Comment: @Joy where do you need them to be stored?

Comment: Generally if we download any images, it will open the dialogue for select the storage location. How can we achieve here @peter

Comment: Ah, you want the client to be able to download the image. Then you do not need to use the Storage SDK, just provide the link to your users, for example https://browsercontent.blob.core.windows.net/blob1/Content/User/3.png. Make sure your container is open for the public, see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-manage-access-to-resources)

Comment: Your solution works and file got created in the provided location, but while execute the below code, it opens the new page and doesn't display anything. 
await blockBlob.DownloadToFileAsync(localPath, FileMode.Create);

How to restrict it?